# laravel-echo, Pusher - is there any way to send message from client to server?

Tags: laravel, websocket, pusher, laravel-echo

I am new in websockets, now i'm trying to figure out, is there any way to send message to server through channel, not by traditional HTTP requests.
My init code:

```
window.Pusher = Pusher

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER ?? 'mt1',
    wsHost: 'localhost',
    wssHost: 'localhost',
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false, 
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});
```

My channel set up and listen code:

```
///..inside store
this.channel = Echo.private(`chat.${this.chat.id}`)
                    this.channel.listen(`.new_message`, (e) => {
                        this.pushMessage(e.data)
                        this.dataPending = false
                    })
```

Laravel code:

```php
//channels.php
Broadcast::channel('chat.{chat}', \App\Broadcasting\ChatChannel::class);
//ChatChannel.php
class ChatChannel
{
    /**
     * Create a new channel instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Authenticate the user's access to the channel.
     */
    public function join(User $user, Chat $chat): array|bool
    {
        return $chat->user_id === $user->id;
    }


}
```

This is client-AI chats, so there is no other user, this join() function is okay.

Listening to events works properly, but i literally can't find any info about broadcasting from client to server. Any similar questions wasn't answered properly.

Comment: This does not seem to be something that is offered by Laravel Echo. You might need to build a websocket solution from scratch

Comment: Okay, this is not a big problem. But main question is how to implement listening on server-side?

Comment: On a PHP serverside (if you go down that route) you can use something like [this](http://socketo.me/docs/websocket) and implement an `onMessage` handler to read incoming messages. On the client side you'd use something similar but for JavaScript. This will need to run on its own, possibly outside of Laravel as a service or using supervisor

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you, this is prettty exhaustive answer!